# Subview isn't positioned correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview, uidatepicker

I am adding a UIDatepicker to a UIViewController, which is the rootview of a UINavigationController, and I use this code to position the Datepicker at the bottom of the screen.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216, 320, 216)];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

This should normally place the picker exactly at the bottom of the screen, but it is 44p missplaced. The Navigationbar is exactly 44p heigh, so I think this is the problem, but I don't know why the frame height includes the height of the navbar, when it doesn't act like a Subview.

I know a simple way would be to substract 44, but I am looking for a solution without any fixed numbers. Is there a way to implement it and can someone please explain me why the view includes the height of the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the *translucent* property of navigation bar to **YES** to solve your problem..

Ex:

```
self.navigationControllerInstance.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: What if you don't want it to be translucent but still want to position without magic numbers?  Seems like a side effect solution ...

Comment: @bryanmac - If you don't want to set the translucent property to YES, you needs to make the view controller's view height as 960(ipad i.e., 1004-44 portraite mode). Similar calculation needed for iphone also. Like this you can handle the frame of view to achieve the requirement. But, it is sure that translucent property is an effective fix for this rather than setting the view frame.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that since your UIViewController is the root view of a UINavigationController it's implicitly including the navigationBar on its bounds.

To get its frame programmatically, you could use:

`CGRect navframe = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 216, 320, 216)];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

try this!

Comment: Sorry, this got me the same result. Setting the navbar to transculent solved it. Thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to hardcode any dimensions. Try this code:

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(picker.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(picker.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(picker.bounds));
[picker setFrame:pickerFrame];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

It works and does not assume that a datepickers height is always 216. That may change in future iOS implementations, so it is better to check the size at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I guess this will solve your problem!